# Pandas sum over with specific column index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume there is a pandas DataFrame such as

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'items':[[101,102],[102,101],[102,103],
                            [101,103],[101,101],[102,102],
                            [103,103]],
                   'value':[12,13,11,15,17,8,19]})
print(df)

        items  value
0  [101, 102]     12
1  [102, 101]     13
2  [102, 103]     11
3  [101, 103]     15
4  [101, 101]     17
5  [102, 102]      8
6  [103, 103]     19
```

I would like to sum over 1st value of `df['items']` in each row such that
[101, 102] + [101, 103] + [101, 101] = 12 + 15 + 17 = 44. Do the same thing for 102 & 103. The final data frame should have something like

```
    0   101     44
    1   102     32
    2   103     19
```

This is my code but it seems to be incorrect

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['items'][1]).agg({'value':sum})
```

Any suggestion? many thanks

Comment: your output doesn't match for the given data

Comment: I think I *would like to sum over 2nd value of df['items']* should have been phrased as *I would like to sum over 2nd value of df i.e. value column* .

Comment: Actually you are summing over the **1st** value of *df['items']* ...

Comment: @StefanoGiannini, thank you. It was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
In [168]: df.groupby(df["items"].str[0]).agg({"value": "sum"})
Out[168]:
       value
items
101       44
102       32
103       19
```

`df["items"][0]` would choose the 0th value of the Series, not each 0th value of the lists in the Series. For that, we use the `.str` accessor. It's short for string but `[..]` is supported by lists too (duck typing) so we can use them on lists as well. Note that Python is 0-indexed, so we use 0 not 1.

Comment: glad to be of help!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing `df['items'][1]` to groupby, you should be passing `df['items'].str[1]`

```py
df.groupby(df['items'].str[1]).agg({'value': sum})
       value
items       
101       30
102       20
103       45
```

Comment: OP asks to sum over 2nd value of `items`

Comment: Yeah, just realized. the disconnect between the question wording and the proposed output.

Comment: Actually I think OP wants *sum over* means you let it run over the possible values, as in the example: `[101, 102] + [101, 103] + [101, 101] = 12 + 15 + 17 = 44`. So yes, groupby 0-th items.

Comment: @QuangHoang actually I think *I would like to sum over 2nd value of df['items']* should have been phrased as *I would like to sum over 2nd value of df* By second value, now I guess OP meant second column i.e. value column and not the 2nd value in `df['items']`

Comment: @ThePyGuy, thank you very much. I just need to change 1 to 0. Then all set. Thanks Again

Comment: @ThePyGuy, sorry, it was a typo. You are correct. I mean to sum over 1st value.